# Extract in, out in OrientDB query

Tags: attributes, extract, orientdb

I have a query in OrientDB as:

```
select in, out from E_Employe
```

- "in" is the link to a vertex from class "User";
- "out" is the link to a vertex from class "Company";
- "E_Employee" is the edge between "User" and "Company".

I need to put instead of "in" some attributes from "User" (for example "username", "email"), and instead of "out", some attributes from "Company" (for example, "name", "address"), and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use dot notation:

```
 select 
    in.username as name, in.email as email, 
    out.name as companyName, out.address as companyAddress 
 from E_Employe
```